# String.append in java

Tags: java, string

```
    String someString = "text";
    someString.append("0").append("1");
```

So, I saw this in some code that actually works (so clearly it's a valid implementation).
This got me wondering how this stuff actually works. I get the whole idea of pointers having nested pointers, but this doesn't seem be the case.
Is it compiling the first append, saying that's a string, and then compiling again?

Comment: There's no `append()` method defined for `String` in the Java language.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, for the reason provided by azurefrog.

Comment: Does String have an `append()` method? Or you are mening `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class does not have any `append` method, so I highly doubt this is the code you really saw.

The real code was probably using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
StringBuilder someString = new StringBuilder("someString");
someString.append("a").append("b");
```

as for how the method works :

> Appends the specified string to this character sequence. The
>   characters of the String argument are appended, in order, increasing
>   the length of this sequence by the length of the argument. If str is
>   null, then the four characters "null" are appended.
>
> Let n be the length of this character sequence just prior to execution
>   of the append method. Then the character at index k in the new
>   character sequence is equal to the character at index k in the old
>   character sequence, if k is less than n; otherwise, it is equal to the
>   character at index k-n in the argument str.

The `append` method return a reference to the object, this is why you can chain the call to `append`.

Now to answer your question on what does the compiler really do, let's have a look at the generated bytecode :

```
   0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3: dup
   4: ldc           #3                  // String someString
   6: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9: astore_1
  10: aload_1
  11: ldc           #5                  // String a
  13: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  16: ldc           #7                  // String b
  18: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said, the `String` class has no method `append` in Java. However, `StringBuilder` has one : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)

As you can see in the javadoc, the methods return a pointer to itself, thus, you can call any method on what is returned.

To simplify, the method is probably implemented somewhere along those lines :

```
public StringBuilder append(String s) {
    // do something with s

    return this;
}
```

This is sometimes called a [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)